# Multiple conditional statements on list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list, list-comprehension

So this is my code and I want to know if I can use list comprehension to execute the same operation (count the clusters within **rows** and output a list of length `df.shape[0]`). There are at least two rows for the same cluster number, but it can be more and they cycles. I tried but couldn't figure it out.
Any suggestions?

My code:

```
    import pandas as pd

    cluster_global = 0
    cluster_relativo = 0
    cluster_index = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['cluster'] == cluster_relativo:
            cluster_index.append(cluster_global)
        elif row['cluster'] == (cluster_relativo + 1):
            cluster_global += 1
            cluster_relativo += 1
            cluster_index.append(cluster_global)
        elif row['cluster'] == 0:
            cluster_global += 1
            cluster_relativo = 0
            cluster_index.append(cluster_global)
```

The DataFrame looks like

| index | cluster |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| n | m<40 |

Comment: Could you clarify why you would *want* to express so many different things as a single comprehension? Also, a small (<20 rows) ready-to-use example of `df` would help to illustrate what your code is intended to do.

Comment: For faster computing while counting the number of clusters, all I've read points out that list comprehension is better than iterrows. Sorry if this is unpractical, it's my very first post here, but here it goes:

my_index = [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
my_values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
from itertools import groupby

result = [0 if index == 0 and key == 0
          else index
          for index, (key, group) in enumerate(groupby(my_values))
          for _ in group
          ]

print(result)
```

Replace my_values in the list comprehension via - df['cluster'].values. to test

Comment: wow, this works fine! honestly i need to read the documentation to get it right, but it is indeed a lot faster. Thank you @Nk03